# $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are unit vectors with angle $\theta$ between them. Show that $\sin(\theta /2 ) = \| \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v} \| /2 $

Tags: vector-spaces

I was trying this problem but I can't solve with the $\sin(\theta /2)$.

I try this:

$$<\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u}>\ = \|\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v} \| \|\mathbf{u} \| \cos\alpha$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{u}$.

$$ <\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v}>\ = \| \mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v} \| \|\mathbf{v}\| \cos\alpha$$

Then I add the equations:

$$<\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}>\ =  2 \| \mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v} \| \cos\frac{\theta}{2}$$

Because $\| \mathbf{u}\| = 1$ and $\| \mathbf{v}\| = 1$. So,

$$\frac{\| \mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v} \|}{2} = \cos \frac{\theta}{2}$$
Maybe I forgot some explanations, but that is my idea however, I can't see how to go from $\cos$ to $\sin$.

Maybe there is another form; thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your notation. What is $\theta$? Is that the angle between $u$ and $v$? What is $\operatorname{sen}(x)$? If $\theta$ is the angle between $u,v$, then $\operatorname{sen}(x)$ clearly isn't the same as $\sin(x)$

Comment: If $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $u,v$, then we have
$$
\cos(\theta/2) = \|u + v\|/2, \quad \sin(\theta/2) = \|u - v\|/2.
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks for the corrections, here is common the notation $sen$ sorry for that. I edite my post.

Comment: in my exercise i have to prove $sin(\theta /2) = \| u + v \| / 2$, maybe this is a mistake and i'm asking for nothing.

Comment: Do they say in the exercise what exactly $\theta$ is?

Comment: $\theta$ is the angle between $u $ and $v$

Comment: Then indeed there must be a mistake somewhere. For example, it's clear that the formula proposed gives the wrong answer when $u = v$.

Comment: Thanks u so much, I will talk to my professor for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be an error in the problem. Consider this simple counter example:

Let $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{v}$, be arbitrary unitary vectors. Then, $\sin\theta=\sin 0=0\Rightarrow \sin(\theta/2)=0$.

However,
$$\frac{||2\mathbf{u}||}{2}=\frac{2||\mathbf{u}||}{2}= 1$$

For the cosine, it works. As far as I can tell, your answer looks correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.